# App.js being rendered twice and auth is not working appropriately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a problem with my routes and I dont know how to fix this. I use redux and localstorage to store my token and I have a isAuthenticated value that checks if I currently have a token, for now this is how I verify my routes.

Anyways I check props.isAuthenticated and whenever I am logged in I have access to the banks route. HOWEVER when I refresh the page it redirects me to the home page and this is the main problem, i want it to stay in the same page. I console logged the value of `props` and whenever I refresh any page I get two props, the first time isAuthenticated is false and the second it is true, so it is rendering twice for some reason. If you guys need any more information please let me know.

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Layout from './hoc/Layout/Layout';
import Home from './containers/Home/Home';
import Logout from './containers/Auth/Logout/Logout';
import * as actions from './store/actions/index';

const Auth = React.lazy(() => {
  return import('./containers/Auth/Auth');
});

const Banks = React.lazy(() => {
  return import('./containers/Banks/Banks');
});

const App = props => {
  const { onTryAutoSignup } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    onTryAutoSignup();
  }, [onTryAutoSignup]);

  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/login' render={props => <Auth {...props} />} />
      <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
      <Redirect to='/' />
    </Switch>
  );

  if (props.isAuthenticated) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/logout' component={Logout} />
        <Route path='/login' render={props => <Auth {...props} />} />
        <Route path='/banks' render={props => <Banks {...props} />} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>{routes}</Suspense>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTryAutoSignup: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState())
  };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(App)
);
```

This is my authCheckState action

```
export const authCheckState = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')
    if (!token && !refreshToken) {
      dispatch(logout())
    } else {
      const expirationDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem('expirationDate'))
      if (expirationDate <= new Date() && !refreshToken) {
        dispatch(refreshAuth(refreshToken))
      } else {
        dispatch(authSuccess(token, refreshToken))
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: check https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/ I hope this can help you

Comment: I'll try this thanks